# when I run the script in the browser it looks like the notebook

Tags: php, easyphp

am 3 days trying to run a test script, with no success. follows picture of the result when I run in chrone and edge
[image]
[image]

please help me

Comment: You can't execute PHP from the browser, unlike HTML, you need to install a webserver on the pc, like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/it/index.html).

Comment: You need to install PHP for windows to be able to get this to run. PHP is run serverside https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iW0B9NTId2g

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: @salvatore Well...he has a webserver... `EasyPHP` - but he is not accessing the files via the webserver but by direct file:/// path

Answer (score 0):

You try to open your php file from the folder. You need to do it from the server. The address in your browser should be : `http://127.0.0.1/phpinfo.php`